# How do I change connection properties in my ssis in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssis

I have this code to execute a package. What the package does is just export very large table data into excel file.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TableToFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SSIS"].ConnectionString);
            var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(connection);

            var package = integrationServices
                .Catalogs["SSISDB"]
                .Folders["MyFolder"]
                .Projects["MyProject"]
                .Packages["MyPackage.dtsx"];

            long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(true, null);

            ExecutionOperation eo = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Executions[executionIdentifier];
            while (!eo.Completed)
            {
                eo.Refresh();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            return Json(new { result = "ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { result = "error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

However, the package has hard-coded connections like sql server source and excel file destination filename. That we can see in connection manager in the package.

I have this code in VB.Net and using a different library it sets also the connection of the package

```
        Dim source As String = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath() & "\export.dtsx"
        Dim p As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package = app.LoadPackage(source, Nothing)
        Dim exec As Executables = p.Executables

        For Each config As ConnectionManager In p.Connections
            Select Case config.Name
                Case "SourceConnectionOLEDB"
                    config.ConnectionString = "..... some connection string here"
                Case "DestinationConnectionFlatFile"
                    config.ConnectionString = file

                    Dim inner As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile90 = CType(config.InnerObject, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile90)

                    For i As Integer = 0 To inner.Columns.Count - 1
                        Dim innerColumn As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFileColumn90 = inner.Columns(i)

                        If i < inner.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                            innerColumn.ColumnDelimiter = delimiter
                        Else
                            innerColumn.ColumnDelimiter = vbNewLine
                        End If
                    Next
            End Select
        Next

        For Each taskhost As TaskHost In exec
            taskhost.Execute(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        Next
```

My problem is how do I change connection string or some settings before I execute the package in my C# code above like my VB.Net does?

Answer (score 0):

since you seem to be using the SSIS catalog, you should also be able to use project environment variables. Basically your package would reference these variables and you would set the values before execution.

There is an explanation on this at http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables